# cannot install ubuntu 13.10 on new HP Spectre 13

Tags: 13.10, laptop, hp

I cannot install ubuntu 13.10 on new HP Spectre 13, it boots onto black screen after selecting Install Ubuntu from bootable USB drive. Thoughts?

Thank you.

Here are the specs:

Windows 8.1 64
• 4th generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U Processor + Intel(R) HD Graphics(For 8GB Memory)
• Onboard 8GB DDR3 System Memory
• 13.3-inch diagonal Radiance Full HD Infinity LED-backlit Display (1920x1080) Touchscreen
• 128GB Flash Solid State Drive
• Webcam and Microphone
• 802.11 AC WLAN and Bluetooth(R) [2x2]
• USB Ethernet Adapter

Answer (score 1):

Folks,  found a fix that worked for me.

[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782)

Does anyone know process to request the creation of a new ubuntu driver for this:
4th generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U Processor + Intel(R) HD Graphics(For 8GB Memory)

Cheers.